# How to set cpp folder for a specific build flavor

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-build-flavors

I have an issue with adding a `cpp` folder and `CMakelist.txt` file to a specific flavor in android studio.

I was working on three separate apps with a unique database structure, so I tried to make these three apps as one application using build flavors and other related settings.

For the first two apps, it did so well, but for the last one, I faced an issue that I had no idea how to add `cpp` folder and `CMakelist.txt` file to that specific flavor using Gradle. As you may have guessed, the last application is NDK based and uses a `CMakelist.txt` file and has an activity that works with JNI.

```
android {
   ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'program'
    productFlavors {
        first {
            dimension = 'program'
            applicationIdSuffix  = '.first'
        }
        second {
            dimension = 'program'
            applicationIdSuffix  = '.second'
        }
        third {
            dimension = 'program'
            applicationIdSuffix  = '.third'

            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    relativeProjectPath "src/third/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
                    version "3.10.2"
                }
            }

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a" }
                }
                debug {
                    ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using a `relativeProjectPath` method in gradle, and expect that `CMakelist.txt` links with my `cpp` folders but nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried it that way. What worked for me in my previous projects is this.

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "program"
    productFlavors {
        ...
        third {
            dimension "program"
            externalNativeBuild.cmake {
                arguments "-DFLAVOR=THIRD_PROGRAM"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your `CMakeList.txt`, do this conditional test

```
if(${FLAVOR} STREQUAL "THIRD_PROGRAM")
    // build your cpp codes for flavor THIRD
else()
    // nothing to build?
endif()
```

Note that my `CMakeList.txt` is in `app/` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I did it as you said and I'm satisfied with the result, but the issue was that my first two apps don't need externalNativeBuild configuration and just the third app seeks for it. In case of this answer, I have to do it for all of the apps, and it leads to the slow building of the first two apps because they have become NDK apps, too.

Comment: Sorry but as far as I can remember, it is not allowed to have a separate `CMakeList.txt` for each build variant. If you happen to solve it, I am eager to know as well. Cheers for now!